# Insert Unicode in GUI Emacs and Xorg

Tags: unicode

I see that for GUI Emacs, we should use ucsc-insert (C-x 8 RET), but this is totally different than under xorg, where we use Control-Shift-u.

Do we have a method that would work in both?

The reason I'm asking is because I have a Moonlander keyboard and I have some keys bound to xorg keyboard combinations for inputing unicode characters which I use often. If there is no such way to have
a unified way of outputing them from the keyboard, it means I would have to have two different keys for each unicode character I wish to have bound to a key.

Comment: What do you mean by *"a method that would work in both"*? Are you looking for how to set a key binding so the same key binding is used for each?

Comment: @Drew yes, I have a Moonlander keyboard, so I have some unicode characters bound to keys which I use often;)

Comment: Please update the question itself, to make this clear. Thx.

Comment: I have updated the question. Would it be possible to define this, like (define-key global-map (kbd "C-S-u") 'insert-unicode-like-in-xorg)

Answer (score 0):

You can just type unicode characters directly. `C-x 8 RET` is there to allow a human to search for the character that they want (notice that it supports autocomplete on character names as well as accepting code point numbers). Similarly, IME features like control-shift-u for entering a unicode code point are also intended as user–facing features (even though it’s pretty poor.)